# Exporting 3D map from ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: fme-form, pdf, arcgis-pro, arcscene, 3d-map

When I use ArcScene 10.4 I can easily export 3D maps (VRML in *.wrl) which I then convert in FME to a *.prc file that can be imported in Adobe Acrobat PDF files (to create interactive 3D maps, readers can navigate, zoom, change colors, etc.)

However when I'm working with ArcGIS Pro, I can't find out how to do this. ArcGIS Pro works perfectly for visualizing 3D and it has many 3D tools and options, but the export of 3D features I haven't found (yet).

How do I export a 3D map from ArcGIS Pro?

(File types *.wrl, *.u3d or *.prc are all fine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a useful work around right now that works in FME

As a reader select your .shp file from ArcGIS Pro.

First you need to transform the shape to an 3D generated environment (important to select the base_elev of your shape (as surface level))

The second transformer extrudes the polygons by their approx_hei (the z-value in meters in your attribute table)

As a writer select a .prc writer (you need .prc for Adobe Acrobat Pro to generate 3D viewers)
[image: FME Workflow, ArcGIS Pro to 3D file (.prc for PDF)]

(Note: the names in my FME are not perfect)

Answer (score 2):

In ArcGIS Ideas there is an enhancement requested to [Support Export of 3D PDF out of ArcGIS Pro](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/12252-support-export-of-3d-pdf-out-of-arcgis-pro) which sounds like the requirement that you are trying to meet.

Consequently, it would appear that exporting to 3D PDF cannot be done by ArcGIS Pro 2.0 or earlier.